# How to set top priority for memory consumption in app Android?

Tags: android, performance

Set top priority for memory consumption for my application on Android and avoid `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

My application is the one that will run on a tablet but need all possible memory available to perform the decryption of files.

Comment: Try <application  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: "need all possible memory available to perform the decryption of files" -- then use C/C++ and the NDK for the decryption. Even with `largeHeap` set to `true`, you will only be able to use a small fraction of the RAM on the device in your app from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to manifest **android:largeHeap="true"** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

It could help if you are running out of memory, for example - loading big bitmaps.

**From documentation**:

In very special situations, you can request a larger heap size by setting the largeHeap attribute to "true" in the manifest  tag. If you do so, you can call getLargeMemoryClass() to get an estimate of the large heap size.

However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such as a large photo editing app).

**From:** 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory

Comment: The problem with large heap is that there is no specification that says how much MBs it is. On different devices you will get different "large heaps" on one device it could be ok but on anotherit could not. In order to say how to solve author's problem is to check what problem he really got :) Decryption is not so memory consuming that one needs "largeHeap"